# Why does the compiler ignore struct elements inside a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, struct

I am using g++ compiler. I wrote the following code which has a template class definition. The class has a struct data-type called node which has elements a and b of the generic type. The class has one function called print which prints p.h where p is a variable of type node of the class object. The compiler does not show any errors although 'h' is not an element of struct node. Why is that?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    template <typename e>
    class mc
    {
      typedef struct node
      {
        e a,b;
      }node;
      node p;
    public:
      void print();
    };

    template <typename e>
    void mc<e>::print()
    {
      std::cout<<p.h;
    }

    int main()
    {
      mc<int> m;
      //m.print();
      return(0);
    }
```

The compiler shows an error only when m.print() is uncommented in main. Why is that?

Comment: You must use the template for it to be instantiated (and compiled)

Comment: I don't see an `h` in `p`.

Comment: How come `node` is `typedef`ed, but `mc` isn't? At least be consistent, though there's very little benefit to the `typedef` in C++ and it also throws in unnecessary stuff to read when looking at that class.

Comment: Ok, even if you ignore the typedef part, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you donot use the object (instance) of a template, compiler only check the logic of the template. The template will not be instantiated. But if you try to use a instance of a template, that template will be instantiated (expanded) then you will see the error that `h` is not a member of `p`.

That is to say that , if you comment out `//m.print()`, the template will be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make writing `template` classes a bit easier, non-invoked `template` methods are not instantiated.

A few things are checked -- the signature of the method, and it does lookup of any methods or functions that involve only data non-dependent on the `template` parameters of the class and the like.

In this case, `p` is technically dependent on the `template` parameters of the class, so the check that `p.h` is valid is done at instantiation.  Now, you could prove that there is no `e` such that `p.h` is valid, but the compiler doesn't have to, so it doesn't bother.

The program may still be ill-formed: there are clauses in the standard where programs can be ill-formed (no diagnostic required) if there are no valid specializations of a `template`, but I do not know if that applies to a method of a `template` or not.

Once you invoke `print`, the method is instantiated, and the error is noticed.

An example of where this is used in the `std` library is `vector` -- a number of its methods, including `<`, blinding invoke `<` on its data.  `vector` does not require that its data support `<`, but it does require it if anyone tries to call `<`.

Modern C++ techniques would involve disabling `vector::operator<` in that case (the standard talks about "does not participate in overload resolution"), and in C++1z this becomes far easier via `requires` clauses (if that proposal ever gets standardized).